# Identifying phrases which contrast two corpora

Tags: nlp, gensim, n-gram, linguistics, phrase

I would like to identify compound phrases in one corpus (e.g. `(w_1, w_2) in Corpus 1`) which not only appear significantly more often than their constituents (e.g. `(w_1),(w_2) in Corpus 1`) within the corpus but also more than they do in a second corpus `(e.g. (w_1, w_2) in Corpus 2)`. Consider the following informal example. I have the two corpora each consisting of a set of documents:

1. `[['i', 'live', 'in', 'new', 'york'], ['new', 'york', 'is', 'busy'], ...]`
2. `[['los', 'angeles', 'is', 'sunny'], ['los', 'angeles', 'has', 'bad', 'traffic'], ...]`.

In this case, I would like `new_york` to be detected as a compound phrase. However, when corpus 2 is replaced by

2. `[['i', 'go', 'to', 'new', york'], ['i', 'like', 'new', 'york'], ...]`,

I would like `new_york` to be relatively disregarded.

I could just use a ratio between n-gram scores between corresponding phrases in corpora, but I don't see how to scale to general n. Normally, phrase detection for n-grams with `n>2` is done by recursing on `n` and gradually inserting compound phrases into the documents by thresholding a score function. This insures that at step `n`, if you want to score the `n`-gram `(w_1, ..., w_n)`, then you can always normalize by the constituent `m`-grams for `m<n`. But with a different corpus, these are not guaranteed to appear.

A reference to the literature or a relevant hack will be appreciated.

Comment: It's not quite clear how in your informal example, the 2nd case should result in a lower propensity for `new` & `york` to be combined. (With more total examples across both corpora of the words appearing together, the case for treating it like a bigram might, under usual assumptions, make the case stronger.) Can you say more about the case/heuristic you're envisioning?

Comment: Also, it's not clear why all potential terms/n-grams that don't appear in one corpus can't just be considered to appear 0 times, or (if necessary) some 0+epsilon plug value. Another helpful reframing might be to work on combined corpora, especially (1) the two combined into one frequency survey; (2) that baseline combined corpora *plus* another repeat of one, or the other, corpora. Then all unigrams/n-grams are always there at the baseline/combined rate - but you'd check if repeating one or the other corpora change frequencies 'enough' for your combination-heuristic.